# Pulling earliest date in specific criteria in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Using google sheets, I'm trying to pull the earliest dates for unique values using the query function.

[The Raw data looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmlWH.png)

I want to pull the data so that I only get the first test completed for each unique identifier provided that test was done within 2 days prior or after their ward admission. So it should spit out something like this:

[The data range I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KndE.png)

I am using the following formula which is nearly what I want, it's just including multiple values for the unique identifers:

```
=Query(Sheet1!1:952,"Select A,B,C,D,E where C > -2 and C < 2 and C is not null and E is not null Order By D",1)
```

[Results I'm getting with the above formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gRPI.png)

I feel like I'm nearly there, I just need to somehow only pull the minimum date values instead of them all. Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually easier to use Sortn with these than query (although you can choose the min value of any individual column (e.g. date) within a group using query, it doesn't give you the min value of any other columns corresponding to that min value, which is what you want). [Sortn](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624?hl=en-GB) has an option to ignore rows that are duplicates with respect to a particular sort key or keys (in this case, Unique Identifier).

```
=sortn(sort(filter(A2:E,C2:C<2),4,1,1,1),999,2,4,1)
```

(if column C can be negative, put another condition in the filter).

[image]